# Tensorflow model training

Tags: python, tensorflow, networking

I am having problem with creating my own model for recognizing pets on images. I'm following Oxford pet recognizer walkthrough but i'm stuck with this error.

```
    python object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py --data_dir=/home/cyber/Downloads/broji/annotations --output_dir=/home/cyber/Downloads/broji/output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 318, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py", line 271, in main
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(FLAGS.label_map_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 119, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: data/pet_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you at least link the aforementioned Oxford Pet Recognizer?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md

Comment: It looks like a simple error: the requested file does not exist. Try with the full path.

Comment: I've tried that but it is the same. Downloaded YOLO and works like a charm.